# Логотип в формате PNG размазывается в Google Chrome, хотя качество картинки отменное

Tags: google-chrome, html, дизайн, png, css

Вставляю логотип в блок на сайте, как фон. В Safari (у меня mac) смотрится отлично. В хроме - тень с какими-то белыми штуками, да и качество вообще страдает. PNG-24 цветовая палитра.

***Вот в Safari***

[image]
[image]

***А вот в Chrome (если приглядеться, видно, что на белом фоне тень (серая) не очень четкая)***

[image]
[image]

Что это такое? Как от этого избавиться? Что я сделал не так?

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: можно ль ссылку онлайн посмотреть? Mac, Safari и Chrome имеются.

Comment: @sergiks http://flaticus.meximas.com/test/
Только залил
Прокрутите страницу чтобы увидеть лого на белом фоне

Comment: @sergiks Ну что?))

Comment: у меня [все выглядит прилично](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x4597v8l7dbhe8/Screenshot%202014-02-25%2023.24.11.png) на свежих FF и Chrome. Предположу, что глюк может быть из-за изменения размера картинки в браузере, т.к. оригинальное изображение 693x500px показывается ужатым до 261x180px.

p.s. не ретина.

Comment: Сижу я со смарта, на вопрос ваш смотрю: сравниваю картинки, которые вы скинули - две капли воды! Картинки чёткие.

Comment: @sergiks У вас выглядит прилично, но в хроме тень какая-то белесая
Ну, с линией белой
Если я сделаю картинку под стать блоку, она будет не очень четкая

Comment: Не вижу там разительных отличий: [difference ваших шотов, усиленный в два раза](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ux9ki6zmzgd2gxo/Screenshot%202014-02-25%2023.51.43.png) показывает очень незначительную разность по контуру, из-за различных алгоритмов рисайза в браузерах, видимо. Но без криминала.

Comment: @sergiks кстати вообще как логотип?))) и идея?))

Comment: по лого не понятно, что за компания/сервис. Что-то с облаками, видимо? Почему диаметр "e" меньше, чем "o"?

Comment: @Sergiks , смотришь на логотип скайпа или fb и становится сразу понятно что за компания/сервис.

Comment: @ИгорьСолдатов , мне нравится лого, но сразу напомнило скайп.

Answer (score 2):

Если используете Retina display,  попробуйте воспользоваться следующими стилями, преждевременно увеличив размер png ровно в два раза:

```
@media only screen and (-Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .icon {
        background-image: url(icon@2x.png);
        background-size: 200px 100px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```